# What gets executed as the server starts vs. as a request comes in?

Tags: django

I've been doing some class hacking in Django. And I call my changes from settings.py as I figure this runs before anything else.

However, I've just come across a situation where this doesn't work for me. So, is there another place *after* settings.py, which I can guarantee will always be run by the server before it starts handling any requests?

Comment: urls.py will be run prior to serving any pages. Would that be good enough?

Answer (score 6):

You should never put code in `settings.py` that requires importing anything from any part of Django.  Since many parts of Django require settings to be available, this is very likely to get you into circular import problems.

Your `ROOT_URLCONF` (`urls.py`) is a reasonable place to put project-level code that you want run once for each server Python process, before any requests are served.

If the code is specific to a particular app (and only needed if that app is in use) then you could put it in that app's `models.py` or `__init__.py`.

For a broader look at the issue, see [this blog post](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/05/server-startup/).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'class hacking' but have you tried calling your changes from ./manage.py?

From [the docs:](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/)

> In addition, manage.py is
>   automatically created in each Django
>   project. manage.py is a thin wrapper
>   around django-admin.py that takes care
>   of two things for you before
>   delegating to django-admin.py:
>
> It puts your project’s package on
>   sys.path. It sets the
>   `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment
>   variable so that it points to your
>   project’s settings.py file.

so if you have some stuff that you want to run after settings.py this might be the case if its a hack you're after.

HTH

Comment: -1 Under any production setup, manage.py is never imported or run at all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the [request_started signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#request-started)?

Comment: -1 If you're monkeypatching built-in classes (what I presume you mean by 'class hacking'), it's crazy to do something on every single request when it only needs to be done once.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put code somewhere in your django project that will get run for certain every time you start up django, pick an app form INSTALLED_APPS. Both the __init__.py and the models.py will be run for sure. They are good places for things like signals or anything you must register.

Comment: -1 Django does not guarantee that all models will be loaded before any requests are served.  Models are only actually loaded if they are imported, or if somebody requests the full list of apps from the app cache.