# Django Reloading on every request

Tags: django, mod-wsgi

I wanted to load some data and keep it in memory as in application scope. Basing on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027421/what-gets-executed-as-the-server-starts-vs-as-a-request-comes-in) and other posts in stackoverflow, I've put the required code snippet in `settings.py`, `urls.py`, `models.py`. I also put print statements to see when it gets executed. I see all the print statements in the server log with every request.

The following are the version details:

1. `Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64`
2. `Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)`
3. `Django 1.4`
4. `Python 2.7.4`

Looks like django is re-loading for every request. I also looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025378/python-module-being-reloaded-for-each-request-with-django-and-mod-wsgi) and confirmed with the admin that `MaxRequestsPerChild` is NOT  1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running in mod_wsgi embedded mode, you will have a multi process configuration, thus can take a while to warm up all processes with your code. Also, Apache will kill off idle processes and so you will see process churn. So what you may be seeing is the result of that.

Add to your debug code the printing out of the process ID to confirm this.

The easiest thing to do is use mod_wsgi daemon mode and restrict yourself to a small fixed number of persistent processes.

Also go watch my PyCon talk about this sort of stuff at:

- http://lanyrd.com/2013/pycon/scdyzk/

Comment: Thanks @Graham. Looks like the problem is solved. After going through your suggestions admin has done changed `WSGIDaemonProcess XXXXX.in user=django1 group=django processes=30 threads=30` to `WSGIDaemonProcess XXXXX.in user=django1 processes=10 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}` 
 in `httpd.conf`. Now once apache has warmed up with all the processes, I don't see any reloading.